# Remove zero rows from Google Sheets pivot table

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I have a pivot table to aggregate some financial balance by counterparties.
[Link to the example.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccwdK8aNjVJWGx2i_Oci9VnmjRdCYiiEgYFpW8gZShg/edit?usp=sharing)

Over time, it's expected that the aggregate amount for most of the parties will be 0. I want to show only those rows in the pivot table where the aggregate is nonzero. Otherwise, my pivot table will be cluttered by tons of empty zero rows.

In the [above example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccwdK8aNjVJWGx2i_Oci9VnmjRdCYiiEgYFpW8gZShg/edit?usp=sharing), this corresponds to hiding John, Mary, and Thomas records.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks @player0, I've added the example to the question.

Comment: it seems you cannot filter by aggregated values in Google Sheets pivot table in easy manner. You may consider usage of another web-based tool for pivot tables that can do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding a filter on top of your pivot table.

1. Select the row with currencies (2nd row of pivot table)
2. Data->Create a filter...
3. Click on the last column
4. Filter by condition...->Custom formula is
5. `=ABS(B3) + ABS(C3) + ABS(D3) > 0`

See [the example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ccwdK8aNjVJWGx2i_Oci9VnmjRdCYiiEgYFpW8gZShg/edit#gid=1924885577).

Answer (score 3):

you could use a double query like:

```
=QUERY(QUERY(Transactions!A1:C, 
 "select A,sum(B) 
  where A is not null 
  group by A 
  pivot C", 1),
 "where Col2>0 
     or Col3>0 
     or Col4>0", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you, what I am looking for is specifically using pivot table for it's "details" capability. I'd like to be able to see detailed information on how was the actual value calculated (double click on cell works for that with Pivots).