# Is there a way to filter with a logical condition covering multiple columns in pivot tables?

Tags: google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, pivot-table

I need to filter rows of a pivot table that have no value in 2 columns. E.g. if rows are people and columns are fruits, I need to filter people who have no apples or pears (but may have other fruits).

I've tried to add a custom formula filter on the "filter" part of the pivot tables, but it is either not working or I'm not getting the syntax right. I'm not sure where I'm supposed to be pointing towards.

This is an example formula I would want to use in my pivot table filter:
`=NOT(AND(ISBLANK(E4); (N4=0)))`

I can have a workaround to this if I filter the actual columns of the sheet, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579047/remove-zero-rows-from-google-sheets-pivot-table), but that also filters the rest of the rows of the sheet, outside the pivot table which I do not want

Comment: "either not working or I'm not getting the syntax right"  What is the problem?  When reading the question title and seeing "Something like this", then I **GUESS** that you can use: `=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(A)), NOT(ISBLANK(B)))`, but I can only guess because it's unknown what  why the original did not work...

Comment: You are correct, I've edited the title to be "OR", I get confused sometimes, I've edited the title. I either don't understand how the custom formula in the pivot table filters should be formatted, with regards to pointing to the correct columns, or they just don't work.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you. I never format a formula, but leave that to the tool (In this case GoogleSheets) to format it.